# How to add keyword to log output in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I want to make it so that there would be a keyword in the logs before the request author, in this line it is "postgres", please tell me how to get it?

```
2023-08-09 14:23:05.910 PL,"postgres","postgres",1212,"::1:50120",64d37719.4bc,2,"",2023-08-09 14:23:05 MSK,3/16,0,LOG,00000,"connection authorized: user=postgres database=postgres application_name=HeidiSQL",,,,,,,,,"","client backend",,0
```

I wanted to implement this through the postgreSQL config **log_line_prefix = 'user=%u'**, but it didn’t work, if you know how it can be implemented, tell me, the config option would be the most convenient for me

Comment: `log_line_prefix = 'user=%u'` works for me.